# SatScan can’t read coordinate file

Tags: coordinates, error, satscan

I just started using SatScan, but I've been getting this error “Reading the coordinates file” repeatedly and can’t run the program. I don’t know what could be the problem. Someone please help.

[image: Coordinate file and SatScan error message]

Comment: Please write out the error in your question and don't post an image.  What does the Coordinate file section in the user guide say about the error, or what it is expecting?  Please edit the question to add more information

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, I used a csv file instead of excel and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. You should delete the 1st coloumn of your data. SatScan doesn't need any explanation in the first row. just exactly put your data without any explanation like we usually did in excel.